# firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged seemingly not refreshing token

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a web app using Firebase for authentication. [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#node.js) states that its id tokens last an hour, and are also refreshed on certain events. So, as instructed, I'm using the [`onIdTokenChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) method to refresh the token like so:

```
async function getFirebaseUserIdToken() {
  const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
  window.localStorage.setItem('idToken', idToken);
  firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async user => {
    if (user) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('idToken', await user.getIdToken());
    }
  });
  return idToken;
}
```

**Problem**: it doesn't seem to work. I still get logged out. It seems to me that `onIdTokenChanged` isn't being called when the token has been refreshed. And I don't know why.

**version data:**

- "firebase": "^7.24.0",
- "react-firebaseui": "^4.0.0",
- "react": "^16.10.2",
- "redux": "^4.0.4",
- "react-redux": "^7.1.3",

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using `onIdTokenChanged` effectively.  The callback is just saving the token to local storage, which doesn't actually do anything for your app.  You need to capture that token and actually use it in your code that requires it.  Putting that listener inside a getter method doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @DougStevenson: it's the token that's in local storage that I send with every API request to ensure the user is authenticated. So when I log in, local storage is where the token is initially set and used. But when it expires, it doesn't seem to get refreshed with whatever new token firebase generated. Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, we can't see any of that code, so you might be doing something wrong there.  In any event, putting onIdTokenChanged in a getter doesn't make much sense,  That's something you'd want to establish globally.  I also wouldn't bother writing it to store.  Just keep it in memory.

Comment: @DougStevenson: that function is only called once on login and then all the api calls get the idToken from local storage.  We’re expecting the observer to get called when the token expires and write the new idToken to local storage so the next api call will have it. But it doesn't now. Can't figure out why. FYI- I sent you a consulting msg/request.

Comment: @SaulFeliz did u figure out the issue? i am also facing the same

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai No...I had to hack my own solution by looking through firebase's code base and using `setInterval()`. It's pretty sad and hacky, but works for now.

Comment: @SaulFeliz are you using the optional force refresh flag in getIdToken? i.e. `user.getIdToken(true)`?

Comment: @cDitch: I'm fairly certain I tried any optional params. But I'm at a different gig with a different code base, so can't confirm or work on this particular issue any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are logged out. But What worked for me is refreshing token in the loop:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
        const minutes=4;
        const interval=minutes * 60 * 10000;
        const handle = setInterval(async () => {
            const user = auth.currentUser;
            if (user) {
                await user.getIdToken(true);
            }
        }, interval);
        return () => clearInterval(handle);
    }, [])
```

And refresh the token in the local storage as a result of this interval using **onIdTokenChanged** method:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (user==null)
        {
            navigate("/Login");
        }
        return auth.onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
            if (!user) {
                setUser(null)
            }   
            else {
                const token = await user.getIdToken();
                
                localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", user.refreshToken);
            }
        })
    }, []);
```

One of my full example you can checkout [here](https://github.com/ProductivityTools-Transfers/ProductivityTools.Transfers.Web/blob/main/src/Session/AuthContext.js)